# trying to query answers for a question using the stack.php

Tags: support, stack.php

I am trying to query stackoverflow and route it to my website via the following

```
<?php
require_once './stackphp_source_0.4/src/api.php';
require_once './includes/function.php';

// Begin by getting a Site object for Stack Overflow.
// We can use 'stackoverflow' or 'stackoverflow.com' here.

$question = new QuestionRequest('http://www.stackoverflow.com', null);
$question = $question->Search("C#");

// paged Response object
$page = $question->Answers()->Exec(); 

?>


<html>
    <head>
        <?php
            include("includes/bootstrap.php");
        ?>
        
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Stack.PHP - User's Questions</title>
  <!-- <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../common/style.css' /> -->

    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include("includes/banner.php"); ?>
        
        <div class="main_content">
              <h2>Questions Asked By User #1 on Stack Overflow</h2>
              
              <?php echo $page->Fetch(); ?>
        </div>


    <?php include("includes/script_includes.php"); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I keep getting the error

> Curl was unable to retrieve the data from the specified URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should be using the latest version of Stack.PHP, which is version 0.5. You can download a tarball here:

> https://launchpad.net/stackphp/0.5/0.5/+download/stackphp-0.5-source.tar.gz

The only file you need to include is `api.php` which is in the `src/` directory.

You will almost never need to create a `Request` object yourself since you can obtain it from a `Site` object. You can do that with:

```
$site = API::Site('stackoverflow');
```

Now you can use `$site` to access the methods available on that site, most of which return a subclass of `Request`:

```
$request = $site->Search('C#');
```

Once you have a request, you need to convert it into a response. This is done as follows:

```
$response = $request.exec();
```

You can then enumerate the items in the response with:

```
while($q = $response->Fetch(FALSE))
{
    // do something with $q here
}
```

For example, `echo $q['title']` will display the question's title.